# Unable to Create Checkbox in DHTMLX

Tags: javascript, frontend, dhtmlx

I am trying to create a checkbox which i checked. I am unable to find the required documentation to create a it. The input to the JS function is a the cell. I am not sure what to do after that.

Here is my code till now:

```
    function eXcell_includeRC(cell) {
    try {
        this.cell = cell;
        this.grid = this.cell.parentNode.grid;
        var cbvalue = regExpGetValueCell;

        if (cbvalue = 'Y') {
            //add something to show a checked checkbox
        } else {
            //add somethig to add an unchecked checkbox
        }
    } catch(error){
        alert (error.toSource());
    }
    return "false";
};
```

This where i am stuck. I checked the below link.
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/grid__basic_operations.html#grid

But the options given in there dont work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to place the required html-content for your checkbox in the setValue function of your custom exCell.

Here you can find a detailed tutorial about building a custom column type in the dhtmlxGrid with the different examples:
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/grid__columns_types.html#customcolumntypes
Pay attention to the "button" column type it is pretty close to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the link.That was really helpful. I tried something like this but nothing shows up on screen

Comment: Somehow i am not able to add my new code. How do i do that. Comments say too long.

Comment: the solution with the example is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924810